# Google Sheets — Missing borders for some cells

Tags: google-sheets

In my current Google Sheets project, I've encountered a weird bug where three of my cells can't have any borders, no matter what I do. In my particular case, the border between cells H70 and I70, H79 and I79 and H83 and I83 don't receive a border.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWsWu.png)

I tried giving

- a **right** border to the cells in column **H**
- a **left** border to the cells in column **I**
- a **vertical inner** border to the **H:I** combination

Additionally, I tried **deleting the rows** 70, 79, and 83, but the issue persists in the same rows.

I can safely say that I have

- no **unique conditional formatting** ("unique" meaning nothing that applies only to those cells) in any of the cells. The only conditional formatting at all is one that changes the text color but definitely not the background color, and only if the cells aren't empty, which these are
- no **"invisible" cell content** that goes beyond the cell borders (the cells are also set to "clip")
- no **script that changes any of the cells in any way**. The only script I have is one I have to manually execute to copy a sheet including all of its protected ranges
- no **protected ranges** anywhere near those cells

Has anyone else ever encountered this problem and maybe knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, after all.

Turns out an ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX()) all the way up and right in cell **L48** had some entries in lines **70**, **79**, and **83**, that were so long they overflowed into those cells. No idea why they overflowed **to the left**, but setting column **L**'s text-wrapping to "clip" solved the problem (and since I only need that column for Data validation, I don't need to see its whole text).

If anyone encounters a similar problem, my advice would be to **change the background and/or text-color** of the affected cells. Since my array way black on black and wasn't directly in one of the affected cells, I was only able to see it when the cells' backgrounds were set to white.

[Content from cell L70 reaching into H70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z27dJ.png)